# If $ x \not\equiv 0, 4 \pmod{8} $, how can I prove that $ x^2 \equiv k^2 \pmod{16} \iff x \equiv \pm k \pmod{8} $?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $ k $ be a positive integer. Let x be a positive integer that satisfies $ x \not\equiv 0 \pmod{8} $ and $ x \not\equiv 4 \pmod{8} $. Then is the following statement true?

$$ x^2 \equiv k^2 \pmod{16} \iff x \equiv \pm k \pmod{8}. $$

---

Example: Let $ x = 13 $. Then $ x^2 = 169 \equiv 9 \pmod{16} $ and $ x \equiv 5 \equiv -3 \pmod{8} $.

---

How can I prove it without enumerating all 16 possible cases for $ k $?

Comment: Show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: There are so few classes $\pmod {16}$...if all else fails, just list them all and check by hand.

Comment: @lulu Is it possible to prove this without enumerating all possible cases by hand? While this is a specific question with modulo 16, if there is a way to prove this without enumerating all cases, it would help me to attack such problems for arbitrary modulus too.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just do the enumeration.  It only takes a second and then you know the answer.  As to generalizations, well of course it depends on the sort of generalization you had in mind.  As a rule though, looking at the congruence $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod n$ is a good place to start.

Comment: You could perhaps learn things by enumerating. for example, $13=-3$ then $13^2=(-3)^2=9$. Which could be useful for other problems.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Yes, enumeration does show that this is true. I am still struggling to prove it without using enumeration though. The part I am having trouble with is: How do we start with a congruence modulo 16 and drop down to a congruence modulo 8?

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you provide a value of $ x $ that is a counterexample?

Comment: For the case in which $x$ is coprime to $16$:  If $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod {16}$ then $(x-1)(x+1)\equiv 0\pmod {16}$ and since $\gcd(x-1, x=1)≤2$ we see that one of the factors must be $0\pmod 8$

Comment: @AnneBauval  Are you possibly overlooking the fact that the OP excluded $x\in \{0,4\}$?

Comment: @AnneBauval  No worries, I made the same error initially.

Answer (score -1):

According to the condition,
$$16|x^2-k^2$$
$$\implies16|(x+k)(x-k) $$
As $(x+k)$ and $(x-k)$ have the same parity, they must both be even.

So, we have a number of sub-cases, one of which is:

$4|(x+k)$ and $4|(x-k)$

This is precisely where $x\equiv \pm k\pmod8$ does not hold anymore.

A good counterexample would be that $256\equiv 16\pmod{16}$ is true, but, $ 16\not\equiv \pm4\pmod8$

I hope your question has been resolved.

Comment: You seemed to have missed the condition that $x \neq 0, 4 \pmod 8$.